# Node-serial port as external module in webpack - module not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, node-serialport

I'm trying to get node-serialport to work with electron and webpack.

I'm [importing serialports as external module](https://github.com/EmergingTechnologyAdvisors/node-serialport/issues/1349):

```
# webpack.config.js

externals: {
  serialport: "serialport"
}
```

This is the code in my app:

```
// read NMEA data from serial port
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
console.log(SerialPort.list());

const Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline;
const port = new SerialPort('/dev/tty.Redmi-ShareGPS', { baudRate: 4800 });
const parser = port.pipe(new Readline({ delimiter: '\r\n' }));



// Open errors will be emitted as an error event
port.on('error', function(err) {
  console.log(err.message);
})

// send NMEA data to GPS.js
parser.on('data', function(data) {
  // gps.update(data);
});
```

Trouble is in first line: `const SerialPort = require('serialport');`

Webpack compiles everything without error, but I have a browser console error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: serialport is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:65651)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:65630)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:31520)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:25595)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at _ol_ (bundle.js:63)
    at bundle.js:66
```

Which origins at this in webpack generated bundle.js:

```
/* 315 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

// read NMEA data from serial port
const SerialPort = __webpack_require__(316);
console.log(serialport.list());

const Readline = SerialPort.parsers.Readline;
const port = new SerialPort('/dev/tty.Redmi-ShareGPS', { baudRate: 4800 });
const parser = port.pipe(new Readline({ delimiter: '\r\n' }));

// Open errors will be emitted as an error event
port.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log(err.message);
});

// send NMEA data to GPS.js
parser.on('data', function (data) {
  // gps.update(data);
});

/***/ }),
/* 316 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

module.exports = serialport;

/***/ })
/******/ ]);
```

The error line is exactly `module.exports = serialport;`

According to [webpack docs on externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#externals), I suppose I somehow need to include serialport as a global variable, but the example is for jQuery which is a js file, and serialport is node module.

How to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many hours of frustration, I moved

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport');
```

from javascript file which is supposed to be bundled by webpack to index.html:

```
<script>
  const SerialPort = require('serialport');
</script>
<script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

SerialPort is now recognized.

Also, it seems like webpack-dev-server doesn't work very well with Electron and serialport. I have to launch full electron app.

Answer (score 2):

#### Try `remote`.

You might also want to try using `remote`:

```
const SerialPort = require( "electron" ).remote.require( "serialport" );
```

Comment: Tried this, got past the webpack error but got errors when loading fs due to electron loading its own version and conflicting with node fs. Unfortunately I had to resort to Patryk's solution even if it feel "dirty"

Comment: Are you using `electron-rebuild` to rebuild your native packages for the version of electron you have? https://github.com/electron/electron-rebuild

Comment: Yep I was, but turns out I was doing it quite wrong as the issue was related to the angular5 typing declaration for serialport that I forgot to add to the service. I followed this response and it worked like a charm: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48252859/angular5-electron-serialport-support/49719282#49719282

Comment: this did it for me, nothing else needed :)

Answer (score 0):

use `eval`

```js
const serialport = eval(`require('serialport')`)
```