# Angular(5)-Electron Serialport Support

Tags: angular, electron

In the past I wrote some applications in `NodeJS`+`TypeScript` with `SerialPort` native module to communicate over `RS232` with different hardware systems.

Now I would like to add serialport to my Angular-Electron app.
So I installed the following:

```
npm install serialport --save
npm install @types/serialport --save
```

I placed `import * as SerialPort from 'serialport'` in `home.components.ts`.

After invoking the code below nothing but errors:

```
//List serial ports
SerialPort.list( (err:Error, ports:any[]) => {
    ports.forEach((port:any) => {
        console.log('Com Name ' +port.comName +
                    ' | Manufac ' +port.manufacturer +
                    ' | Vendor ID '+ port.vendorId );
    });
});

//open com port 4
this.com = new SerialPort('COM4', {baudRate : 19200}, (err: Error) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Open Error: ', err.message);
    }
});
```

Browser DevTool Log:

```
getRoot     @   vendor.bundle.js:87243
bindings    @   vendor.bundle.js:87139
./node_modules/serialport/lib/bindings/linux.js     @   vendor.bundle.js:109113
webpack_require     @   inline.bundle.js:55
(anonymous)     @   vendor.bundle.js:108666
./node_modules/serialport/lib/bindings/auto-detect.js   @   vendor.bundle.js:108669
webpack_require     @   inline.bundle.js:55
./node_modules/serialport/lib/index.js  @   vendor.bundle.js:109589
webpack_require     @   inline.bundle.js:55
(anonymous)     @   main.bundle.js:268
./src/app/components/home/home.component.ts     @   main.bundle.js:348
webpack_require     @   inline.bundle.js:55
./src/app/app-routing.module.ts     @   main.bundle.js:38
webpack_require     @   inline.bundle.js:55
./src/app/app.module.ts     @   main.bundle.js:164
webpack_require     @   inline.bundle.js:55
./src/main.ts   @   main.bundle.js:418
webpack_require     @   inline.bundle.js:55
0   @   main.bundle.js:507
webpack_require     @   inline.bundle.js:55
webpackJsonpCallback    @   inline.bundle.js:26
(anonymous)     @   main.bundle.js:1
```

Any hint how to get it running? I need SerialPort support in my Angluar-Electron application.
In Python or C that's no problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how are you building/bundling your code?

Comment: Hi Tim,
I am using https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron to build my code
If you want I can zip and share project files. Just using NodeJS and Typescript everything works fine with SerialPort

Answer (score 6):

If you go to https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron you can see how to use native libraries at the bottom the page.

In electron.service.ts add the import:

```
import * as SerialPort from 'serialport';
```

Then inside the ElectronService class add:

```
serialPort: typeof SerialPort;
```

Then inside the constructor add to the if statement the following:

```
if(this.isElectron()){
   [...]
   this.serialPort = window.require('serialport');
}
```

Back in the home.components.ts file add the import

```
import {ElectronService} from '../../providers/electron.service';
```

Inject the service into the constructor:

```
constructor(private electron:ElectronService){...}
```

Finally, in the ngOnInit() function you can use the serial port like so:

```
this.electron.serialPort.list().then((ports:any)=>{
   [...]
}).catch((err:any)=>{
   [...]
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was forgetting `serialPort: typeof SerialPort;` and it was causing all sort of weird error message that lead me to obscure and niche github issues.

Comment: How do you connect the Serialport? I tried with this.port = new SerialPort(....) but on compiling i got some errors. With just serialport.list() it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The angular-electron seed also install the npm modules in the /dist folder, so you will also need to run electron-rebuild on the serialport module in the dist folder to make it work.

As it is described in the angular-electron seed.

> If you need to use NodeJS native libraries, you MUST add it manually in the file webpack.config.js in root folder

```
module.exports = {
  "externals": {
    "serialport": "require('serialport')"
   }
}
```

in the package.json add:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "electron-rebuild -f -w serialport"
}
```

and then run

```
npm start
```