# serial port package gives error in Angular Project

Tags: angular, electron, serial-port

I'm trying to implement data reading through a serial port in my Angular project (using electron), but after installing the serial-port package I'm getting errors of 'Module not found'.

The followings are my reference for the project

- [Angular(5)-Electron Serialport Support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48252859/angular5-electron-serialport-support)
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport

[The Error I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0Rar.png)

electron service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as SerialPort from 'serialport';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ElectronService {
  serialPort: typeof SerialPort;
  constructor() {
    this.serialPort = require('serialport');
  }
}
```

My type-script file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as SerialPort from 'serialport';
import { ElectronService } from './electron.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})


export class AppComponent {
  title = 'serial-port';
  serialPort: typeof SerialPort;

  constructor(private electron: ElectronService) {

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.electron.serialPort.list().then((ports: any) => {
      {
        console.log("true")
      }
    }).catch((err: any) => {
      {
        console.log("Error" + err)
      }
    });
    console.log(this.serialPort);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, download the `ngx-electron` [package from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-electron). This makes the IPC a lot easier. Run:

`npm install ngx-electron --save`

In your `electron service` file, try doing the following:

- (Important note) this `ElectronService` from `ngx-electron` is **NOT** your your `ElectronService` that you have in your code here. Maybe change its name to `SerialPortService`:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ElectronService } from "ngx-electron"; // <=== Added this line
// import * as SerialPort from 'serialport'; <==== Removed this line

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class SerialPortService{
  public SerialPort: any;
  constructor(private electron: ElectronService) {
    this.SerialPort = electron.remote.require("serialport");   // <=== Crucial line here
  }
}
```

Then, in your `component.ts` you can now call serialport methods:

```js
  constructor(private electron: SerialPortService) {}  // <=== Notice I changed the name here.

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.electron.serialPort.list().then((ports: any) => {
      // your code
  }
```