# Using serialport with electron and webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, electron

I'm trying to use serialport with a react+electron+webpack application. I first tried [this](https://github.com/serialport/electron-serialport) example, which works fine. The problem comes when I try to use serialport in an electron application that also uses webpack.

I make my electron+webpack app using [this electron forge example](https://www.electronforge.io/templates/webpack-template).
I then install serialport (npm install serialport --save) and try to import it in the project with:

```
(const {SerialPort} = require('serialport');)
```

This results in a whole lot of errors:

```
    Electron Forge was terminated:
    ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/home/rha/my-new-app/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/dist',

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in '/home/rha/my-new-app/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/dist'
    
    BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
    This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
    
    If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
        - install 'util'
    If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "util": false },

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/rha/my-new-app/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/dist'
    
    BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
    This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
    
    If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
    If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false },

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/rha/my-new-app/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/dist'
    
    BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
    This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
    
    If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
    If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false },

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in '/home/rha/my-new-app/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/dist'
    
    BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
    This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
    
    If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
        - install 'util'
    If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "util": false },

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/rha/my-new-app/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/dist',ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/rha/my-new-app/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/dist',

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in '/home/rha/my-new-app/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/dist'
    
    BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
    This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
    
    If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
        - install 'util'
    If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "util": false },

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/rha/my-new-app/node_modules/@serialport/parser-byte-length/dist'
    
    BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
    This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
    
    If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
    If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false },

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/rha/my-new-app/node_modules/@serialport/parser-cctalk/dist'
    
    BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
    This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
    
    If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
    If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false },

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/rha/my-new-app/node_modules/@serialport/parser-delimiter/dist'
    
    BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
    This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
    
    If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
    If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false },

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/rha/my-new-app/node_modules/@serialport/parser-inter-byte-timeout/dist'
    
    BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
    This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
    
    If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
    If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false },

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/rha/my-new-app/node_modules/@serialport/parser-packet-length/dist'
    
    BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
    This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
    
    If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
    If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false },

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/rha/my-new-app/node_modules/@serialport/parser-ready/dist'
    
    BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
    This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
    
    If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
    If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false },

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/rha/my-new-app/node_modules/@serialport/parser-regex/dist'
    
    BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
    This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
    
    If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
    If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false },

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/rha/my-new-app/node_modules/@serialport/parser-slip-encoder/dist'
    
    BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
    This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
    
    If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
    If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false },

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/rha/my-new-app/node_modules/@serialport/parser-slip-encoder/dist'
    
    BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
    This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
    
    If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
    If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false },

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/rha/my-new-app/node_modules/@serialport/parser-spacepacket/dist'
    
    BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
    This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
    
    If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
    If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false },

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/rha/my-new-app/node_modules/@serialport/stream/dist'
    
    BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
    This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
    
    If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "stream": require.resolve("stream-browserify") }'
        - install 'stream-browserify'
    If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "stream": false },

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/rha/my-new-app/node_modules/node-gyp-build',ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/rha/my-new-app/node_modules/node-gyp-build'
    
    BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
    This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
    
    If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
    If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false },

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/home/rha/my-new-app/node_modules/node-gyp-build'
    
    BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
    This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
    
    If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser") }'
        - install 'os-browserify'
    If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "os": false }
```

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50554290/10588032) suggested using

```
const SerialPort = require( "electron" ).remote.require( "serialport" );
```

If I try that I get the following errors:

```
    Electron Forge was terminated:
    ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/rha/my-new-app/node_modules/electron',

ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/rha/my-new-app/node_modules/electron'
    
    BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
    This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
    
    If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
        - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
        - install 'path-browserify'
    If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
        resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
```

Things I have tried that did NOT give any different result:

- Adding `resolve: {fallback: {fs: false}}` to the webpack config
- Adding `"browser": { "fs": false, "path: false, "os": false}` to package.json
- Adding `config.node = {fs: 'empty' }` to the webpack config
- Adding `target: 'node'` to the webpack config

Any help to solve this is appreciated.

Comment: are your using serialport in the front-end side or backend?

Comment: I'm very new to this, so I'm not sure. All I've done is follow this electron-forge setup https://www.electronforge.io/guides/framework-integration/react, install serialport, and then I've added the import line in app.jsx

Comment: the thing is that serialport as far as i know is a node.js module but the app.jsx is front end